# Google Calendar API 403 error

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-calendar-api, python-social-auth

I want to use Google Calendar API in my Django web app.

I successfully got the access token using [python social auth](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Using that token, I tried calling list calendar API with python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Below is my code:

```
import requests

token = ...

endpoint = "https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList"

headers = {
    "Authorization":"Bearer " + token,
}

requests.get(endpoint,headers=headers).json()
```

However, I got the following response:

```
u'error': 
    u'code': 403, 
    u'message': u'Insufficient Permission', 
    u'errors': 
        u'domain': u'global', 
        u'message': u'Insufficient Permission', 
        u'reason': u'insufficientPermissions'
```

How can this be solved? 
I really want to solve this problem without using any other libraries including [API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/).

Comment: How are you getting your token?

Comment: @AChampion Using python social app
    `def get_access_token(request):`
    `social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')`
    `return social.extra_data['access_token']`

Comment: The authorization backend which I'm using is [this](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/social_core/backends/google.py)

Comment: I'm assuming that you have given the original access token the right scopes to access calendar?

Comment: @AChampion I think I missed that part. Can you tell me how I could grant calendar access to the token? (with python requests or python social auth if possible)

Comment: Can you post your `python social auth` code? Assuming the project/client token has the calender api enabled then you need to pass a scope parameter through the social auth, so you get `?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` appropriately encoded on the auth request.

Comment: A quick check on `python social auth` docs seems you need to define `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']`

Comment: Thank you! Setting `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE` solved the problem.